# Multiple submit button fail to find the handler method in asp.net core 3.1 razor page application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a single form which has two button one to upload image using ajax call  & other is main submit button which  saves all the data.

I am still very new to asp.net core and trying different thing to learn asp.net core with razor page.

I read lot of article about multiple form submit but most of then where using two form with submit button for each.

My issue is when i hit the submit button it fails to find the handler method, after full days troubleshoot nothing worked and last few article point to error/failure to antiforgery, i not sure how to implement it in below code as i tried few but they gave error may be article where old referencing core 2.2 etc [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064246/asp-net-core-razor-ajax-post-400-bad-request)  [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373229/400-bad-request-when-post-ing-to-razor-page/48373549#48373549)

I am not sure about the what exactly is causing the issue any help would be appreciate.

I am trying to upload Image using Ajax method in asp.net core Razor pages, I am main form in will all input fields are kept and with the form for Fileupload i am also added addition button which is for file upload using Ajax, When i hit the

`<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" asp-page-handler="OnPostUploadImage" id="btnUploadImage" />`

i want it to call `OnPostUploadImage` method in pageModel file but it alway goes to default `OnPost` method. when i rename the `OnPost` to `OnPost2` nothing happend..

How can i call `OnPostUploadImage()` on button `btnUploadImage` click event.

When i hit click `btnUploadImage` it generates following error on browser console

**Error in FF**

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
>   https://localhost:44364/Admin/News/NewsCreate?handler=OnPostUploadImage
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

**Error in Chrome**

> jquery.min.js:2 POST
>   https://localhost:44364/Admin/News/NewsCreateMultipleSubmit?handler=OnPostUpLoadImage
>   400 (Bad Request)

event though path looks fine but it cant find it as per error message

```
 @page
    @model BookListRazor.Pages.Admin.News.NewsCreateModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "News Create";
        Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
    }


     <div class="border container" style="padding:30px;">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="text-danger" asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
                <input hidden asp-for="News.NewsImage" />
                <input id="fileName" hidden value="" />

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label asp-for="News.NewsHeading"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <input asp-for="News.NewsHeading" class="form-control" />

                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="News.NewsHeading" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label asp-for="News.NewsImage"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        @*<input asp-for="News.NewsImage" type="file" class="form-control" id="NewsImage">*@
                        @*Photo property type is IFormFile, so ASP.NET Core automatically creates a FileUpload control  *@
                        <div class="custom-file">
                            <input asp-for="NewsImageForUpload" class="custom-file-input form-control">
                            <label class="custom-file-label">Click here to change photo</label>
                                                <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" asp-page-handler="OnPostUploadImage" id="btnUploadImage" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <span id="imageStatus" class="text-danger"></span>
                    <span asp-validation-for="NewsImageForUpload" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-3 offset-3">
                        <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-success form-control">Back to List</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
            <script>

                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $("#btnSave").addClass("disable-button");

                    $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                        var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                        $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
                        $("#fileName").val(fileName);
                        $("#btnSave").removeClass("disable-button");
                    });

                    if ($("#fileName").val() == "") {
                        //alert("Select Image...");;
                    }
                });

            </script>
        </div>
        @section Scripts{
            <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />

            <script>
 $(function () {
                $('#btnUploadImage').on('click', function (evt) {
                    console.log("btnUploadImage");
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    console.log("btnUploadImage after evt.preventDefault()");
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Page("", "OnPostUploadImage")',
                        //data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function () {
                            alert('Uploaded by jQuery');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
            </script>
            }
```

**.cs file CODE**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {

                return Page();
            }
        }

        public IActionResult OnPostUploadImage()
        {

            //Some code here
        }
```

Comment: _OnPostUploadImage_ should be just _UploadImage_ (in the ajax call)

Comment: @Steve, It doesnt work as suggested by you.. not sure what is what at first i was so happy to see your comment with a simple fix but it doesnt work, i even name `UploadImage` as my method in .cs file and in ajax also that didnt work, it give same error in console

Comment: Do not change the name on the PageModel class. The convention is every action starts with OnGet, OnPost etc.. custom actions called by ajax should be _"url:", "/index?handler=UploadImage"_  Also POST commands should include the AntiForgeryToken. This is done automatically when _submit_ from a form, but not with ajax calls. You could try to add in ajax _headers: {
                        RequestVerificationToken:
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                    },_

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you add the following code to the `ConfigureServices` method of startup.cs：

```
 services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

If you want to enter the `OnPostUploadImage` method, the url of the Ajax request needs to be changed to `@Url.Page("", "UploadImage")` without adding OnPost.

And the Ajax request should send the `anti-forgery token` in request header to the server.

Change your ajax as follow:

```
@section Scripts{
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    <script>
 $(function () {
                $('#btnUploadImage').on('click', function (evt) {
                    console.log("btnUploadImage");
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    console.log("btnUploadImage after evt.preventDefault()");
                    $.ajax({ 
                        url: '@Url.Page("", "UploadImage")',
                        //data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                            xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                                $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                        },
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function () {
                            alert('Uploaded by jQuery');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
}
```

You can refer to [this](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) for more details.

Comment: @Yougqing, My first attempt didn't work. i will try again

Comment: I did exactly as you had mentioned but it doesn't call the `UploadImage`. i dont get any errors either...on button click in only get alert message `Uploaded by jQuery` nothing else